# Proof of statement involving primality

Tags: number-theory, discrete-mathematics

I wanted to prove this statement:

$\forall a \in \mathbb{N^{>1}}, (\neg Prime(a) \Rightarrow \exists b \in \mathbb{N}, Prime(b) \land (b|a) \land (b \leq \sqrt{a}))$

I am allowed to use the fact that $\forall e,r,t \in \mathbb{N^+}, rt \leq e \Rightarrow (r \leq \sqrt{e}) \lor (t \leq \sqrt{e})$ in my proof

I know that by definition, this statement must be true, but I still want to prove it. I believe proof by contradiction is a good way to proof this statement, so I will assume that the hypothesis and the negation of the conclusion are true.

Proof:

Let a be an arbitrary natural number greater than 1. I will assume that a is not a prime number. I will also assume that $\forall b \in \mathbb{N}, \neg Prime(b) \lor (b\nmid a) \lor (b > \sqrt{a}))$

Since a is not a prime number, by Fundamental Theorem, $a = yz$, where $y, z$ are prime numbers.

Then $b > \sqrt{yz}$ and $b\nmid yz$.

Since b is also not a prime number, then it too can be written in the form of unique prime factors...

Could someone please help me complete this proof? I'm completely lost past this point.

Comment: It does not follow from $a$ being prime that it is the product of two primes. For instance $a = 12$.

Comment: I think you want to use induction here. Write $a = yz$ with $1 < y,z < a$. At least one of $y$ and $z$ are $\leq \sqrt{a}$. Say for concreteness it is $y$. If $y$ is a prime you are done, otherwise...

Answer (score 1):

This is false:

> Since $a$ is not a prime number, by Fundamental Theorem, $a=yz$, where $y,z$
>   are prime numbers.

Just think about $16 = 4 \times 4$.

You can say that at least one of $y$ or $z$ is no larger than $\sqrt{a}$. Then look at a prime factor of that one.

Note. English is much easier to read  than formal statements with logical symbols, and it's  just as rigorous. You should write your proofs in English unless your instructor requires the logical symbols.

Comment: How could i represent $a$ then?

Comment: @YoelEmbide Variables get letters. Use English for things like "implies" and "and" and "or" and  "therefore" and "there exists" and "for every".